# How to print more than 100 copies?

Tags: printing

I have a label printer, which I use to create stickers for bread bags for my small business. I often print 500-800 labels at once, but in Ubuntu the maximum number of pages is limited to 100.

How to increase this number?

Comment: I posted an answer BUT if this is a GUI that does not allow for more than 2 digits you should file a bug against that package :)

Comment: How can I check if the limit is in the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

See  `man lpadmin` and the parameter `job-page-limit=value` for a hard limit on the amount of pages.

cups also has quotas that might be an issue:

> CUPS supports page and size-based quotas for each printer. The quotas
> are tracked individually for each user, but a single set of limits
> applies to all users for a partiuclar printer. For example, you can
> limit every user to 5 pages per day on an expensive printer, but you
> cannot limit every user except Johnny.
>
> The job-k-limit, job-page-limit, and job-quota-peiod options determine
> whether and how quotas are enforced for a printer. The
> job-quota-period option determines the time interval for quota
> tracking. The interval is expressed in seconds, so a day is 86,400, a
> week is 604,800 and a month is 2,592,000 seconds. The job-k-limit
> option specifies the job size limit in killobytes. The job-page-limit
> option specifies the number of pages limit.
>
> For quotas to be enforced, the period and at least one of the limits
> must be set to a non-zero value. The following options will enable
> weekly quotas with the given size and page count limits:
>
> **/usr/sbin/lpadmin -p printer -o job-quota-period=604800  -o job-k-limit=1024
> /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p printer -o job-quota-period=604800 -o job-page-limit=100**
>
> Or, you can combine all three options on the same line.
>
> While there is no way to query the current quota state for a
> particular user, any application can request a list of jobs for a user
> and printer that can be used to easily determine that information.

And [cups](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.3/options.html) also supports command line printing copies:

> Printing Multiple Copies Both the lp and lpr commands have options for
> printing more than one copy of a file:
>
> **lp -n num-copies filename lpr -#num-copies filename**

So if you happen to know the file that needs to be printed you could do this from command line too.

Comment: So I checked /etc/cups/printers.conf, and there's a line for the printer in question "PageLimit 0", which should be no limit.

I then tried printing more than 100 pages from LibreOffice, and that submitted just fine. So I guess it's not a CUPS issue?

The Document Viewer print dialog doesn't allow more than 100 copies either.

I normally print the labels from Inkscape, but it seems that the print dialog is the same as for, for example, Document Viewer. LibreOffice print dialog is different.

Perhaps it's really the GUI?

Comment: I still have this same issue... I haven't been able to find a workaround. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1335881 Any ideas for workarounds??

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a workaround for this... Perhaps I'm the only one who needs it, but just in case.

In Printer Properties, I can set the number of copies in Job Options. Let's say I put 1000 copies there.

Then, on Print Dialog, I just enter 1 to number of copies. Then 1000 labels will be printed. If I enter 2 copies, 2 labels will print, not 2000.

So it does not work if you put 100 copies in Job Options and then try to print 10 copies from Print Dialog.

So it works, somehow :)