# Adding Page Quotas to the network printers

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I want to set up a daily page quota , for all the printers connected to the network ( not for one local printer ). I know that there is a CUPS option to achieve this (`-o job-page-limit=value`), but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print more than 100 copies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/403296/how-to-print-more-than-100-copies)

Comment: @eyoung100: Similar problems, but this question is asking how to set a quota as opposed to removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up a printer using the `lpadmin` command, you can specify the quota settings.

Particularly, there are two values you should be interested in:

- **`job-page-limit`**
  This lets you set the number of pages in the limit, for a specified time period.
- **`job-quota-period`**
  This lets you decide how long the page limit quota lasts.

For example, if you want to set users to be able to print a max of 20 pages per day from the printer `myprinter`, you would use the following command (as root):

```
lpadmin -p myprinter -o job-quota-period=86400 -o job-page-limit=20
```

You must run this command once per printer on each computer that is directly connected to the printer in question.

If you wish to set a non-expiring limit, set `job-quota-period` to `0`.

Some caveats though:

- These quotas apply to *everyone*, and there is no way to change this. Root is just as affected by this quota as anyone else
- Counting can be wonky. For example, a person at (quota - 1) current pages can easily send a job of any size and it will still print.
- Jammed and aborted jobs still cont towards the quota
- Error messages are confusing to end users, and give no information.

<sup>[Source 1](https://community.kde.org/Printing/CUPS/Quotas) [Source 2](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/CUPS-printing.html#id2647322)</sup>

Comment: Kaz Wolfe , ya that will absolutely work for a local printer ! what I need is to try this  for a whole network I mean all the printers connected to the network ?

Comment: @SamahSH You need to run this command once for each computer on your network, and once again for each printer on your network, if I recall correctly. Shell scripting would come in handy for this. Note though that these limits are not global. Give me some time and I'll try to find some global limit rules

Comment: I'll be so grateful !!

Comment: @SamahSH Unfortunately, it does not look like CUPS has any ability to do global quotas. This is a software limitation and there doesn't seem to be a current way around it.

Comment: thank you so much for your help ! I have another question about how to get information about every user like how much pages he had printed .... do u have any idea about it ?

Comment: @SamahSH You should ask that as a separate question, but you should be able to use the CUPS GUI at `http://localhost:631/jobs?which_jobs=completed` to see a list of all (saved) completed jobs. From there, you can get user reports for the print server in question.

Comment: I already did !

Comment: it shows the name as unknow ? am i the only one who have this problem ?